# How to set the transfer mode to ASCII in SFTP (version 3) using Perl

Tags: perl, sftp

I have a requirement to transfer the files using SFTP (version 3) in Perl. While transferring the files, I need to set the transfer mode to ASCII.

Can some one please confirm, it if is possible using any of the Perl modules (`Net::SFTP`/`Net::SFTP::Foreign`/any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign):

```
$sftp->put($local_from, $remote_to, conversion => 'unix2dos');
```

See [On the fly data conversion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#On-the-fly-data-conversion).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Salva. Can I use this with sftp protocol version3?  I mean does it work?

Comment: The "unix2dos" conversion is performed locally before the transfer (as suggested in my answer). So this solution is SFTP version-independent. You of course have to use a correct conversion. The "unix2dos" would be used if you upload from Unix to Windows. Use "dos2unix" for the other direction.

Comment: Hi Salva, I am getting the error: "Connection to remote server stalled" . Can you pls have a look at the below code and help me? I even tried to sftp by removing the conversion part. But still got the same issue. It is failing at the 2nd step "$ftp_file->put"
Code :
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
$ftp_file = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(host => $ftp_address, user => $ftp_user_id, passphrase => $ftp_password)or die "Unable to establish SFTP connection".$ftp_file->error;
$ftp_file->put($ftp_source,$ftp_dir_chg,conversion => 'unix2dos') or die "Unable to transfer: " .$ftp_file->error;

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply! So, even after converting the files locally, does SFTP will default it to Binary while transferring?

Also, Can you please have a look at the above issue and help me with your suggestions?

Comment: Yes, SFTP version 3 always uses binary transfer. Note that it is not a problem, as the file you are transferring is already in the correct format after the conversion (if you use the correct one).

Comment: @Edu: regading the connection stalled error, enable debugging mode (`$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug=-1`) and add the output into your question above.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP version 3 only support binary transfer :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 

Can I convert the file to dos(unix2dos) format on local machine and then transfer it to remote server? I cant test the file at the remote server. Please help. Will this work?

Comment: Thanks Stevieb and Sebastien. If I need to send an ASCII file to the remote server, I will do "unix2dos -c ascii file" and then transmit(sftp) it. But while sftp'ing the file, will it defaults it to binary format?

Answer (score 1):

In SFTP version 3, there's only a binary mode.

So if a program wants to use the ASCII/text mode, it has to know/guess the target system text file format, convert the file/contents before upload, and upload the converted file/contents (in the "binary" mode). While some SFTP clients has the feature built it, the Perl Net::SFTP have not. Do you have to convert the file/contents yourself, before passing it for upload to the Net::SFTP.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply.

Yes, I need to convert the files to ASCII format and send the files to the remote server. But I am limited to use only SFTP protocol Version3.

Comment: No you do not need to convert the files to "ASCII" format. There's nothing like that. You need to convert the files to text format used by the target platform.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your time and support!!! Below is the Solution that I have applied for the given requirement.

Step1: Connect to the server using `NET::SFTP::Foreign` module:
`$sftp_file = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, $user);`.

Step2: Check for the target server type(unix/windows).

- If Unix : no conversion needed as I am sending the file from Unix system.
- If Windows, do UNIX2DOS:
  `$sftp_file->$direction("$src", "$trgt", conversion=>'unix2dos')`.

This method will do on the fly data conversion.